# Grid layout internet explorer not working like expected

Tags: html, css

Currently I'm checking my website in all browsers and found a problem. Normally this tabs should looks like this:

[image]

But when I open the page in the IE it looks like this:

[image]

I've checked the DOM and B is under A. I've did it like described in the CSS documentation but it's not working. This is my CSS for this tab:

```
ul.tabs {
    display: grid;
    display: -ms-grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE/Edge 10-15 [support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) an [older version](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-grid-layout-20110407/) of the CSS-grid spec.

Among other things, auto-placement is missing.

https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/11/26/should-i-try-to-use-the-ie-implementation-of-css-grid-layout has a list of differences.

You need

```
ul.tabs #tab1 {
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
}
ul.tabs #tab2 {
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir. IE & Edge is a whole bunch of sh**. You need to do so much things different just for this two browsers.

Comment: Some suggest making two layouts for your webapp: designing the mobile layout to not use grid, then just giving people with old browsers the mobile layout.